# How to remove the attribute "disabled" from input siblings when i click on a submit input

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this problem: i need to remove the "disabled" attibute from the siblings inputs of submit input. Here is the html:

```
<td>
<input type="hidden" value="2000000000002_STATUTO_07_10_2010.gif" name="nomeDocumento" disabled="true">
<input type="hidden" value="811ecdd0-65e9-49d6-8d9d-8b7c9d9b6407" name="UUID" disabled="true">   
<input type="submit" value="cancella" name="cancella">
</td>
```

i need a simple way using jquery to remove the disable attribute when i click on the submit.
I tried:

```
$('input[name=cancella]').click(function(){
$('this').prev().removeAttr('disabled');
$('this').prev().prev().removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

But i doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The `disabled` attribute should either have no value or a value of `disabled`, i.e. `<input name="foo" disabled>` or `<input name="foo" disabled="disabled">`. Also, you may be confused about properties and attributes: jQuery's `attr()` and `removeAttr()` methods actually deal with properties, not attributes.

Comment: Have you tried `elementNode.disabled = false`? I don’t see why even using jQuery for something that simple.

Comment: @user1598585 27.000 points of stackoverflow later i would say yes, but at the time i was a junior :P

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti ROFL, damn me for not reading the dates of the questions I am commenting on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('input[name=cancella]').click(function(){
   $(this)
      .closest('td')
      .find('input[name!='+this.name+']')
      .attr('disabled', false);
});
```

Fabrizio Calderan `.prevAll()` way is better.
However, `.siblings()` could be even better, so it doesn't matter where the siblings are.

```
$('input[name=cancella]').click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('input').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

Using `.attr('disabled', false)` should work as well and could be more reliable.

Comment: thanks to all of you, the main error was in the use of $('this') instead of $(this). I'll keep this thing in mind from now on! :)

Comment: A wrapper to change the value of an attribute? God, jQuery’s philosophy is unbelievable.

Comment: @user1598585 a wrapper to changes the attribute value of nodes (plural) in a collection that is. And note, there's a significant difference between attribute and property in the DOM, so we also have .prop(propertyName[, value]) =P

Comment: @BGerrissen I repeat my previous comment replacing the appropriate terms to match what you just explained. =P

Answer (score 1):

Ciao,

have you tried .prevAll() ?

```
$('input[name=cancella]').click(function(){
  $(this).prevAll().removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

Note: this is an object, not a string literal (you wrote 'this')

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove quotes around this i.e.

```
$('input[name=cancella]').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().removeAttr('disabled');
    $(this).prev().prev().removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

this is your object not value for attribute [name/id]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **.siblings()** traversing method:

```
$('input[name=cancella]').siblings().removeAttr('disabled');
```

Have a look at this link [JQuery Sibling](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: And also, like others noticed, you must write $(this) and not $('this').

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[name=cancella]').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');
}
```